# Is this sentence a run-on sentence?

Tags: complex-sentences

> The milk having soured, Martha drank her coffee black.

Is this sentence a run-on sentence, or is it an (grammatically) acceptable sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A run-on sentence is one in which two or more independent clauses are joined without correct punctuation or without the use of a conjunction.

The sentence in the example is not a run-on sentence. It has only one independent clause. *The milk having soured* is an introductory participial phrase and is correctly followed by a comma.

Here's an example of a run-on sentence with two independent clauses:

> The milk had soured, Martha had her coffee black.