# Can I use a comma after an apology?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, sentence, sentence-patterns

I apologize, you can return the item to the store.

Is the sentence structure correct or did I need to use a period instead?

Comment: A question which is very very nearly a duplicate, because the answer actually answers yours: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10412 (You have two independent clauses. and a comma is not correct.)

Comment: (And just to be clear, it has nothing to do with "apology" or any other kind of reported speech; it's just about joining two independent clauses.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that you could correctly say "Sorry, you can return the item to the store."  That avoids the independent clause problem.